# How to call and print only Event Types of Event Plugin

Tags: plugins, craft4, events

How to call and print only Event Types (title and handle of event types) of Event Plugin -> https://verbb.io/craft-plugins/events/features

**Moderator Added from Comments:**

I need to filter the events based on event types, I am using radion buttons inside a form to select the event type and than pass that value to URL as param. than i am getting that value to filter the events, as follows :
`{% set selectedCategory = craft.app.request.getParam('category') ?? 'all' %} {% paginate craft.events.events.type(selectedCategory).limit(12) as pageInfo, pageEntries %}`

I need to filter the events based on event types, I am selecting the event type and then pass that value to URL as param. then I am getting that value to filter the events, as follows :

`{% set selectedCategory = craft.app.request.getParam('category') ?? 'all' %} {% paginate craft.events.events.type(selectedCategory).limit(12) as pageInfo, pageEntries %}`

I have tried `{% set eventTypes = craft.events.getAllTypes() %}` Neither the property "getAllTypes" nor one of the methods "getAllTypes()", ....." exist and have public access in class "verbb\events\variables\EventsVariable".

Comment: Voting to close because the question lacks details. Please explain what you're trying to do, what you have tried so far, and in what way it's not working as expected.

Comment: I need to filter the events based on event types, I am using radion buttons inside a form to select the event type and than pass that value to URL as param. than i am getting that value to filter the events, as follows : {% set selectedCategory = craft.app.request.getParam('category') ?? 'all' %}

 {% paginate craft.events.events.type(selectedCategory).limit(12) as pageInfo, pageEntries %}

Comment: I need to filter the events based on event types, I am selecting the event type and then pass that value to URL as param. then I am getting that value to filter the events, as follows : 
{% set selectedCategory = craft.app.request.getParam('category') ?? 'all' %}

 {% paginate craft.events.events.type(selectedCategory).limit(12) as pageInfo, pageEntries %}

I have tried 
{% set eventTypes = craft.events.getAllTypes() %}

Neither the property "getAllTypes" nor one of the methods "getAllTypes()", ....." exist and have public access in class "verbb\events\variables\EventsVariable".

Comment: Please edit your question and add that info, and include the code examples as code blocks. It's very hard to read in the comments.

Comment: I've modified the question to include the asker's comments in the question body. Cheers, all!

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [documentation on available variables](https://verbb.io/craft-plugins/events/docs/template-guides/available-variables) of the plugin. There's a method on the `craft.events` variable, `craft.events.getEventTypes()`, which will return all event types.